# Writing the path of a dragdrop file to a textbox

Tags: drag-and-drop

EDIT: The code below is a class I created in order to have a drag/drop richtextbox in which dragging a file into it causes the information inside the file appear in the richtextbox. This works perfectly, I even made it so decimal characters over 128 appear as binary so I can see bitmap images to some degree.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Troy_PCL_Utility
{
    public class DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        public DragDropRichTextBox()
        {
            this.AllowDrop = true;
            this.DragDrop += DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop;
        }

        public static class BinaryFile
        {

            private static string[] __byteLookup = new string[300];



            static BinaryFile()
            {
                //CHARACTERS: All Control ASCII Characters
                for (int i = 0x00; i < 0x1E; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = ((char)i).ToString(); }

                // Display printable ASCII characters
                for (int i = 0x1E; i < 0x7E; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = ((char)i).ToString(); }

                //BITMAPS: Display non-printable ASCII characters
                //for (int i = 0; i <= 0x00; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = "\\" + i.ToString(); }
                for (int i = 0x7E; i <= 0xFF; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = Convert.ToString(i, 2); } //As Binary  
                //for (int i = 0x00; i <= 0xFF; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = "\\" + i.ToString(); } //As Characters 

            }

            public static string ReadString(string filename)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

                return String.Join("", (from i in fileBytes select __byteLookup[i]).ToArray());
            }
        }

        public void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            //string[] fileText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
            string[] fileText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

            if (fileText != null)
            {
                foreach (string name in fileText)
                {
                    try
                    {
                         this.AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString (name) + "\n -------- End of File -------- \n\n");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in addition to dragging and dropping content into this richtextbox, I would also like textbox2 on my main form to populate with the path from which the file came from so if the user is dealing with several files they can double check to see which one they are viewing and from which directory.

So I have this class (DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox), and I have this other class (Main Form). I'm not sure how to accomplish this task. Should the code to copy the directory into textbox2 belong in my DragDrop class (above), is that even possible? Or should I create an event from the richtextbox in my main?

I tried clicking on the richtextbox (that derived from my DragDropRichTextBox class) and then created a drag/drop event from where I tried to make it so dragging and dropping copy the file path to textbox2, but I had no luck. Here is the code I tried. I don't feel confident in it:

```
private void dragDropRichTextBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = (string) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
            textBox2.Text = fileName;
        }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for the new guy? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That problem started in the DoDragDrop() method, the one began the D+D operation.  It exposed the text in the file, not the path of the file.  With a fairly heavy "of course it did", that's what users typically expect to happen.  They already know the path of the file, they want to move the content.  We can't see that code.

Comment: I edited and expounded upon my question. I hope this makes more sense. If that directory is there I can also do other things with it such as open the file in another program based on that string, or I can send raw data from that file path to the printer. This is why I'm trying to accomplish this. Thanks for your answer I appreciate the help.